# How can I send two arguments in a selector method?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

In the following, how can I send two arguments in `togButton` method? I tried, but it did not work.

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(togButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 4):

control targets only accept one argument for their actions: the control that's being manipulated. There's no way to do what you want (the OS just doesn't support it).

Comment: Actually, it's entirely valid to accept zero or two arguments as well. See my answer. In any case, the parameters are predefined and another method (such as subclassing) must be used to pass app-specific data to the action selector.

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to put in there? Maybe you can use the `tag` property, or if that's not sufficient, subclass UIButton and add instance variables that you can then access in `-togButton:`.

Answer (score 1):

The action selector called by a button tap can have zero, one, or two parameters. The first is the sender (the button that was tapped) and the second is the event (the tap).
See the [target-action mechanism](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol?language=objc) for controls:

```
- (void)action
- (void)action:(id)sender
- (void)action:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

As Thomas Müller suggests, the best way to pass app-specific data to your action selector is by subclassing UIButton (or, in the case of a button on a UITableViewCell, you can add the app-specific data to a UITableViewCell subclass and access the cell as the button's superview.superview).

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a work around to get data from UI component

```
-(void) switchChanged:(id) sender
{
    UISwitch* switchControl = (UISwitch*)sender;
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[sender superview];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    cell.textLabel.text =" change text title";
}
```

now you have cell and indexPath and you can do what you want. I hope I helped.

Also you can use structs to wrap your arguments in one parameter.

Comment: For many years now, the table view cell will not be the control's direct superview.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to send two arguments to the method is to wrap them in a class.  For example, if the two are arguments are strings then you would have a class solely comprised of string iVars.

Comment: ... so how would you send this class?

Answer (score -2):

```
[Class instancesRespondToSelector: @selector (setTo:over:)]
```

I remember seeing this Objective-C code in a book.

Comment: if this is a  misunderstanding of mine, please let me know.

Comment: That tests wether or not instances can handle the setTo:over: message. It doesn't help with sending multiple arguments in a target action. What other languages do you know? I'll try to translate the statement to an equivalent.

Comment: @outis

but this code is shown in Stephen's book like this,

if ( [mySquare respondsToSelector: @selector (setWidth:andHeight:)] == YES )
   NSLog (@”mySquare responds to setWidth:andHeight: method”);


Result,

mySquare responds to setWidth:andHeight: method

...?

I was thinking it works, for SEL also.



I am not arguing, just making myself clear...about idea.

Comment: @outis, i know c and a bit of java too.

Comment: The code in your answer is basically equivalent to `try {Class<?>[] types={int.class, int.class}; MyClass.class.getMethod("setToOver", types); hasMethod=true; } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {hasMethod=false;}`, assuming the `setToOver` method takes two ints. It merely tells you whether a class has a method; it doesn't call the method. See http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reflect/ for more info on `getMethod` and reflection.