# action:@selector in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, button, action, selector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I send two arguments in a selector method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857817/how-can-i-send-two-arguments-in-a-selector-method)

I am writing an action for a button. But the method that I write as the selector takes in two parameters. how would I write the method name in the code:

```
action:@selector(myMethod)
```

Comment: -1,This user can change question dynamically..!

Comment: That is not possible, you may only use one parameter. And btw, that question has been asked plenty of times here on SO.

Comment: @Dinesh every user can - within 5 minutes you can without triggering an edit event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only argument passed to "action" methods is the `sender`, which is the view that triggered the action (and it's optional).  So you can't pass multiple arguments to an action method, because there are not multiple arguments to send.

But you can simply call another method from your action, which can contain whatever arguments you want.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  myButton.action = @sel(myAction);
}

- (void)myAction {
  [self someMethod:@"first argument" withOtherArg:@"second argument"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**First thing:** you should accept more answers before asking something new, people will tend to not help you.

**The answer:**

Use an dictionary where you can put the 2 values you wanted to pass as parameters.This away you will only have one parameter to pass (the dictionary itself). It makes the code cleaner and gives you the flexibility to pass more parameters if you need in the future. Don't forget to leave some comments, so you don't forget what are you putting inside the dictionary.

Comment: this solution is not possible since i think an uibutton only sends itself. (unless you subclass it of course)